# Can't connect to network with TL-WN722N (AR9271) USB adapter

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, atheros

I already tried couple guides to solve my problem, but still I am not able to connect with my TL-WN722N to wifi network.

Device is up and recognized.

```
joe@G580:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09da:000e A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:1468 Syntek 

joe@G580:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

joe@G580:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for joe: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:d3900000-d393ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:1.2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=3.8.0-35-generic firmware=1.4 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

joe@G580:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So I already installed drivers and firmware. I tried to install Win drivers with ndiswrapper, but I got an error message that ndiswrapper is not installed(solving this issue is in progress). This device was working before I had to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04. Now I can see avaible wifi networks, but I'm not able to connect to any of them. When I try to connect to wifi network, it's still trying to connect again and again but it fails every time.

I'm looking for your advices(I'm really desperate now!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Now I feel like a fool!

After couple days of trying to solve this issue I've found this guide:

[WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure)

so I used the command from step 2 - the long one.

In the output I've found that TL-WN722N support channels from 1 to 11. Try to guess what is the channel of my network...yes, it is channel 13.

Sollution found, problem solved.

We can close this topic :-D

Comment: I  trap into same problem with **TL-WN722N**. `iwlist chan` show me that device support only channel 1-11 but I set channel to 12 in my router to better avoid interference with another wifi devices.